# How to apply dcolumn in my longtable case? Need help

Tags: longtable, dcolumn

I have the follwoing table: 
[image]

In panel 5, I want to decimal match the `0.018` and `0.069`.

[image]

However, my code consists of `\begin{longtable}{*{12}{c@{}>{$}c<{$}}}`, I wonder how should I put`d{-1}` in the arguement?
The following is a more complete snapshot of my code

```
\documentclass[10pt,a4paper]{article}
\usepackage{booktabs}
\usepackage[singlelinecheck=false, font={large, bf}]{caption}
\usepackage{array,lscape,longtable}
\usepackage[a4paper, total={6in,10in},top=2cm]{geometry}
\usepackage{siunitx,amsmath,dcolumn}
\newcolumntype{d}[1]{D{.}{.}{#1}}
\begin{document}
\begin{landscape}
\vspace*{-1.5cm}
\setlength{\tabcolsep}{5pt}
\begin{longtable}{*{12}{c@{}>{$}c<{$}}}
\caption{\large{Summary Statistics}}\label{tab:addlabel}\\ \multicolumn{13}{@{}p{1.05\linewidth}@{}}{useless space}\\
\toprule
         \multicolumn{1}{c}{Year}& \multicolumn{1}{c}{Observations}& \multicolumn{1}{c}{Observations}&\multicolumn{1}{c}{No.Firms}&\multicolumn{1}{c}{MeanNPV} &\multicolumn{1}{c}{MeanNPR}& \multicolumn{2}{c}{MarShare\$}   & \multicolumn{2}{c}{MarShare#} &       \multicolumn{1}{c}{MarkNPV}&\multicolumn{1}{c}{MarkNPR}\\ \cmidrule(lr){7-8} \cmidrule(lr){9-10}
         \multicolumn{1}{c}{}& \multicolumn{1}{c}{(NoShareholder)
}& \multicolumn{1}{c}{(Shareholder)}&\multicolumn{1}{c}{(No Shareholder)}&\multicolumn{1}{c}{(NoShareholder)} &\multicolumn{1}{c}{(Shareholder)}&
      \multicolumn{1}{c}{Buy(B)}&\multicolumn{1}{c}{Sell(B)} &       \multicolumn{1}{c}{Buy(000,000)}&\multicolumn{1}{c}{Sell(000,000)}\\
       \multicolumn{1}{c}{}& \multicolumn{1}{c}{(1)
}& \multicolumn{1}{c}{(2)}&\multicolumn{1}{c}{(3)}&\multicolumn{1}{c}{(4)} &\multicolumn{1}{c}{(5)}&
      \multicolumn{1}{c}{(6)}&\multicolumn{1}{c}{(7)} &       \multicolumn{1}{c}{(8)}&\multicolumn{1}{c}{(9)}&\multicolumn{1}{c}{(10)}&\multicolumn{1}{c}{(11)}\\ \midrule
    \endfirsthead
    \caption{\textbf{\large{Summary Statistics} - Continued}} \\
    \toprule
      \multicolumn{1}{c}{Year}& \multicolumn{1}{c}{Observations}& \multicolumn{1}{c}{Observations}&\multicolumn{1}{c}{No.Firms}&\multicolumn{1}{c}{MeanNPV} &\multicolumn{1}{c}{MeanNPR}& \multicolumn{2}{c}{MarShare\$}   & \multicolumn{2}{c}{MarShare#} &       \multicolumn{1}{c}{MarkNPV}&\multicolumn{1}{c}{MarkNPR}\\ \cmidrule(lr){7-8} \cmidrule(lr){9-10}\\  \multicolumn{1}{c}{}& \multicolumn{1}{c}{(NoShareholder)
}& \multicolumn{1}{c}{(Shareholder)}&\multicolumn{1}{c}{(No Shareholder)}&\multicolumn{1}{c}{(NoShareholder)} &\multicolumn{1}{c}{(Shareholder)}&
      \multicolumn{1}{c}{Buy(B)}&\multicolumn{1}{c}{Sell(B)} &       \multicolumn{1}{c}{Buy(000,000)}&\multicolumn{1}{c}{Sell(000,000)}\\  \multicolumn{1}{c}{}& \multicolumn{1}{c}{(1)
}& \multicolumn{1}{c}{(2)}&\multicolumn{1}{c}{(3)}&\multicolumn{1}{c}{(4)} &\multicolumn{1}{c}{(5)}&
      \multicolumn{1}{c}{(6)}&\multicolumn{1}{c}{(7)} &       \multicolumn{1}{c}{(8)}&\multicolumn{1}{c}{(9)}&\multicolumn{1}{c}{(10)}&\multicolumn{1}{c}{(11)}\\
      \midrule
      \endhead
       \midrule
    \multicolumn{13}{r}{\footnotesize\itshape       
                        Continue on the next page}
\endfoot
    \bottomrule
\endlastfoot
1994    & 2,822                 & 3,531              & 1,392                 & -0.086                & -0.085                & 0.531            & 1.376                                                               & 158.712       & 286.982        & -0.443 & -0.288 \\
1995    & 3,766                 & 4,724              & 1,631                 & -0.233                & -0.232                & 0.281            & 3.191                                                               & 58.814        & 499.643        & -0.838 & -0.789 \\
1996    & 4,993                 & 6,114              & 2,118                 & -0.181                & -0.181                & 0.391            & 4.946                                                               & 72.252        & 2006.669       & -0.854 & -0.930 \\
1997    & 5,814                 & 6,999              & 2,350                 & -0.211                & -0.210                & 0.577            & 6.954                                                               & 80.721        & 1596.603       & -0.847 & -0.904 \\
1998    & 7,317                 & 8,800              & 2,685                 & 0.017                 & 0.018                 & 0.936            & 12.013                                                              & 132.938       & 2244.135       & -0.855 & -0.888 \\
1999    & 10,716                & 12,459             & 3,056                 & 0.069                 & 0.069                 & 1.755            & 17.062                                                              & 172.648       & 1471.266       & -0.813 & -0.790 \\
2000    & 20,588                & 23,242             & 3,786                 & -0.007                & -0.006                & 2.992            & 35.909                                                              & 348.423       & 1635.910       & -0.846 & -0.649 \\
2001    & 17,613                & 19,787             & 3,194                 & -0.149                & -0.149                & 1.531            & 21.781                                                              & 261.413       & 1383.436       & -0.869 & -0.682 \\
2002    & 15,837                & 17,773             & 2,976                 & -0.105                & -0.105                & 1.229            & 14.055                                                              & 227.652       & 973.902        & -0.839 & -0.621 \\
2003    & 14,205                & 15,989             & 2,584                 & -0.241                & -0.241                & 1.060            & 18.975                                                              & 114.725       & 1035.963       & -0.894 & -0.801 \\
2004    & 18,017                & 20,370             & 3,197                 & -0.246                & -0.246                & 1.043            & 21.405                                                              & 130.550       & 1093.540       & -0.907 & -0.787 \\
2005    & 17,743                & 19,976             & 3,145                 & -0.231                & -0.230                & 1.924            & 20.957                                                              & 214.510       & 1029.413       & -0.832 & -0.655 \\
2006    & 19,013                & 21,275             & 3,200                 & -0.259                & -0.259                & 1.969            & 27.839                                                              & 126.122       & 1096.229       & -0.868 & -0.794 \\
2007    & 23,753                & 25,662             & 3,407                 & -0.160                & -0.160                & 3.210            & 31.636                                                              & 250.604       & 1329.962       & -0.816 & -0.683 \\
2008    & 30,537                & 30,565             & 3,292                 & -0.064                & -0.063                & 7.171            & 20.560                                                              & 784.786       & 884.918        & -0.483 & -0.060 \\
2009    & 22,468                & 22,469             & 2,398                 & -0.181                & -0.180                & 1.718            & 23.160                                                              & 457.969       & 1058.823       & -0.862 & -0.396 \\
2010    & 27,574                & 27,573             & 2,789                 & -0.216                & -0.215                & 2.941            & 39.861                                                              & 1575.958      & 1894.168       & -0.863 & -0.092 \\
2011    & 28,544                & 28,544             & 2,953                 & -0.183                & -0.183                & 3.409            & 43.146                                                              & 351.198       & 2013.673       & -0.854 & -0.703 \\
2012    & 26,785                & 26,786             & 2,777                 & -0.234                & -0.233                & 4.890            & 49.250                                                              & 465.384       & 1886.073       & -0.819 & -0.604 \\
2013    & 28,140                & 28,144             & 2,813                 & -0.277                & -0.277                & 5.546            & 62.036                                                              & 414.053       & 2194.972       & -0.836 & -0.683 \\
2014    & 23,603                & 23,612             & 2,916                 & -0.264                & -0.264                & 2.624            & 40.205                                                              & 186.281       & 1398.489       & -0.877 & -0.765 \\
2015    & 20,968                & 20,979             & 2,799                 & -0.241                & -0.240                & 2.779            & 37.524                                                              & 179.134       & 1184.230       & -0.862 & -0.737 \\
2016    & 17,190                & 17,792             & 2,449                 & -0.286                & -0.286                & 3.140            & 33.824                                                              & 155.227       & 747.809        & -0.830 & -0.656 \\
2017    & 17,559                & 18,540             & 2,410                 & -0.330                & -0.330                & 2.101            & 43.482                                                              & 111.983       & 963.327        & -0.908 & -0.792 \\
2018    & 16,071                & 17,156             & 2,243                 & -0.289                & -0.289                & 1.931            & 31.389                                                              & 97.476        & 572.353        & -0.884 & -0.709 \\
Overall & 441,636               & 468,861            &                       & -0.187                & -0.187                &                  &                                                                     &               &                &        &         \\ \bottomrule   
\end{longtable}
\end{landscape}
\end{document}
```

Comment: Will you add more data later (more rows)? If not why did you decide to use the `longtable`  environment? Currently the table seems to fit onto a single page.

Comment: As the table currently is too wide for the page, would it be acceptable for you to introduce linebreaks in the column headers?

Comment: @leandriis Hi leandriis, it is already a two-page table, and I did not screen shot the second page. I realise the column headers are too wide, can you teach me how to do linebreaks in the column headers? I am not entirely clear what you mean by that and how will this solve the question.

Comment: @veryBigman: Sorry for the confusion. My last comment was somewhat unrelated to your actual question but more a suggestion on how to fix the additional problem of the table being too wide for the page. Also, is there a reason why you prefer a `dcolumn` solution over a `siunitx` solution?

Comment: @leandriis I solved the issue by myself! Thanks! I am so happy now.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Since the numbers in the 11 numeric columns require both alignment on the respective decimal markers *and* the typesetting of thousands-separators, I recommend using the `S` column type of the `siunitx` package over the `D` column type of the `dcolumn` package.

A nice side-effect of using the `S` column type is that it suffices to enclosed objects that shouldn't be aligned on decimal markers in curly braces; it is *not* necessary to write `\multicolumn{1}{c}{...}`. Observe that in the code below, I've actually eliminated all hard-coded comma characters; it's the software setting `group-minimum-digits=4, group-separator={,}` that instructs LaTeX to typeset them.

To make the large table a bit easier to read, I would also add a bit of extra whitespace after every fifth row; this may be accomplished via the `\addlinespace` directive.

[image]

```
\documentclass[10pt,a4paper]{article}
\usepackage{booktabs}
\usepackage[singlelinecheck=false, font={large, bf}]{caption}
\usepackage{array,lscape,longtable}
\usepackage[a4paper, total={6in,10in},top=2cm]{geometry}
\usepackage{siunitx,amsmath}
%% define a variant of the 'S' column type:
\newcolumntype{T}[1]{S[table-format=#1,
        group-minimum-digits=4, group-separator={,}]}

\begin{document}
\begin{landscape}
%\vspace*{-1.5cm}  % not needed 
\setlength{\tabcolsep}{3pt} % default: 6pt
\begin{longtable}{@{} l *{2}{T{6.0}} T{4.0} *{2}{T{-1.3}} 
                    T{1.3} T{2.3} *{2}{T{4.3}} *{2}{T{-1.3}} @{}}
\caption{Summary Statistics}
\label{tab:addlabel}\\ 

\toprule
Year& {Observations}& {Observations}&
{No.Firms}&{MeanNPV} &{MeanNPR}& 
\multicolumn{2}{c}{MarShare\$} & 
\multicolumn{2}{c}{MarShare\#} &       
{MarkNPV}&{MarkNPR}\\ 
\cmidrule(lr){7-8} \cmidrule(lr){9-10}
& {(NoShareholder)}& {(Shareholder)}&{(No Shareholder)}
& {(NoShareholder)} &{(Shareholder)}&{Buy(B)}& {Sell(B)} 
& {Buy(000,000)}&{Sell(000,000)}\\
& {(1)}& {(2)}& {(3)}&{(4)} &{(5)}
& {(6)}& {(7)}& {(8)}&{(9)}&{(10)}&{(11)}\\ 
\midrule
\endfirsthead

\caption{Summary Statistics -- Continued} \\
\toprule
Year & {Observations} & {Observations}
&{No.Firms}&{MeanNPV} &{MeanNPR}
& \multicolumn{2}{c}{MarShare\$}   
& \multicolumn{2}{c}{MarShare\#} 
& {MarkNPV}&{MarkNPR}\\ 
\cmidrule(lr){7-8} \cmidrule(lr){9-10}\\  
& {(NoShareholder)}& {(Shareholder)}&{(No Shareholder)}
& {(NoShareholder)} &{(Shareholder)}& {Buy(B)}& {Sell(B)} 
& {Buy(000,000)} & {Sell(000,000)}\\
& {(1)}& {(2)}& {(3)}&{(4)} &{(5)}
& {(6)}&{(7)} & {(8)}&{(9)} &{(10)}&{(11)}\\
\midrule
\endhead

\midrule
\multicolumn{12}{r@{}}{\footnotesize\itshape Continued on the next page}
\endfoot

\bottomrule
\endlastfoot

1994    &  2822 &  3531 & 1392 & -0.086 & -0.085 & 0.531 &  1.376 & 158.712 &  286.982 & -0.443 & -0.288 \\
1995    &  3766 &  4724 & 1631 & -0.233 & -0.232 & 0.281 &  3.191 &  58.814 &  499.643 & -0.838 & -0.789 \\
1996    &  4993 &  6114 & 2118 & -0.181 & -0.181 & 0.391 &  4.946 &  72.252 & 2006.669 & -0.854 & -0.930 \\
1997    &  5814 &  6999 & 2350 & -0.211 & -0.210 & 0.577 &  6.954 &  80.721 & 1596.603 & -0.847 & -0.904 \\
1998    &  7317 &  8800 & 2685 &  0.017 &  0.018 & 0.936 & 12.013 & 132.938 & 2244.135 & -0.855 & -0.888 \\
\addlinespace
1999    & 10716 & 12459 & 3056 &  0.069 &  0.069 & 1.755 & 17.062 & 172.648 & 1471.266 & -0.813 & -0.790 \\
2000    & 20588 & 23242 & 3786 & -0.007 & -0.006 & 2.992 & 35.909 & 348.423 & 1635.910 & -0.846 & -0.649 \\
2001    & 17613 & 19787 & 3194 & -0.149 & -0.149 & 1.531 & 21.781 & 261.413 & 1383.436 & -0.869 & -0.682 \\
2002    & 15837 & 17773 & 2976 & -0.105 & -0.105 & 1.229 & 14.055 & 227.652 &  973.902 & -0.839 & -0.621 \\
2003    & 14205 & 15989 & 2584 & -0.241 & -0.241 & 1.060 & 18.975 & 114.725 & 1035.963 & -0.894 & -0.801 \\
\addlinespace
2004    & 18017 & 20370 & 3197 & -0.246 & -0.246 & 1.043 & 21.405 & 130.550 & 1093.540 & -0.907 & -0.787 \\
2005    & 17743 & 19976 & 3145 & -0.231 & -0.230 & 1.924 & 20.957 & 214.510 & 1029.413 & -0.832 & -0.655 \\
2006    & 19013 & 21275 & 3200 & -0.259 & -0.259 & 1.969 & 27.839 & 126.122 & 1096.229 & -0.868 & -0.794 \\
2007    & 23753 & 25662 & 3407 & -0.160 & -0.160 & 3.210 & 31.636 & 250.604 & 1329.962 & -0.816 & -0.683 \\
2008    & 30537 & 30565 & 3292 & -0.064 & -0.063 & 7.171 & 20.560 & 784.786 &  884.918 & -0.483 & -0.060 \\
\addlinespace
2009    & 22468 & 22469 & 2398 & -0.181 & -0.180 & 1.718 & 23.160 & 457.969 & 1058.823 & -0.862 & -0.396 \\
2010    & 27574 & 27573 & 2789 & -0.216 & -0.215 & 2.941 & 39.861 &1575.958 & 1894.168 & -0.863 & -0.092 \\
2011    & 28544 & 28544 & 2953 & -0.183 & -0.183 & 3.409 & 43.146 & 351.198 & 2013.673 & -0.854 & -0.703 \\
2012    & 26785 & 26786 & 2777 & -0.234 & -0.233 & 4.890 & 49.250 & 465.384 & 1886.073 & -0.819 & -0.604 \\
2013    & 28140 & 28144 & 2813 & -0.277 & -0.277 & 5.546 & 62.036 & 414.053 & 2194.972 & -0.836 & -0.683 \\
\addlinespace
2014    & 23603 & 23612 & 2916 & -0.264 & -0.264 & 2.624 & 40.205 & 186.281 & 1398.489 & -0.877 & -0.765 \\
2015    & 20968 & 20979 & 2799 & -0.241 & -0.240 & 2.779 & 37.524 & 179.134 & 1184.230 & -0.862 & -0.737 \\
2016    & 17190 & 17792 & 2449 & -0.286 & -0.286 & 3.140 & 33.824 & 155.227 &  747.809 & -0.830 & -0.656 \\
2017    & 17559 & 18540 & 2410 & -0.330 & -0.330 & 2.101 & 43.482 & 111.983 &  963.327 & -0.908 & -0.792 \\
2018    & 16071 & 17156 & 2243 & -0.289 & -0.289 & 1.931 & 31.389 & 97.476  &  572.353 & -0.884 & -0.709 \\
\addlinespace
Overall &441636 &468861 &      & -0.187 & -0.187  \\ 

\end{longtable}
\end{landscape}
\end{document}
```

Answer (score 2):

Here is my suggestion using `dcolumn` to align the numbers with respect to `.` or `,`, an abbreviation for "Shareholder"  and some linebreaks in the column headers:

[image]

```
\documentclass[10pt,a4paper]{article}
\usepackage{booktabs}
\usepackage[singlelinecheck=false, font={large, bf}]{caption}
\usepackage{array,lscape,longtable}
\usepackage[a4paper, total={6in,10in},top=2cm]{geometry}
\usepackage{siunitx,amsmath,dcolumn}
\usepackage{makecell}
\newcolumntype{d}[1]{D{,}{,}{#1}}
\newcolumntype{e}[1]{D{.}{.}{#1}}
\begin{document}
\begin{landscape}
\vspace*{-1.5cm}

\begin{longtable}{@{}c
                     d{3,3}
                     d{3,3}
                     d{1,3}
                     e{-1,3}
                     e{-1,3}
                     e{1,3}
                     e{2,3}
                     e{4,3}
                     e{4,3}
                     e{-1,3}
                     e{-1.3}@{}}
\caption{\large{Summary Statistics}}\label{tab:addlabel}\\ 
\toprule
         \multicolumn{1}{c}{Year}& \multicolumn{2}{c}{Observations}&\multicolumn{1}{c}{No.Firms}&\multicolumn{2}{c}{Mean}& \multicolumn{2}{c}{MarShare\$}   & \multicolumn{2}{c}{MarShare\#} &       \multicolumn{2}{c}{Mark}\\ \cmidrule(lr){2-3} \cmidrule(lr){5-6} \cmidrule(lr){7-8} \cmidrule(lr){9-10} \cmidrule(l){11-12}
         \multicolumn{1}{c}{}& \multicolumn{1}{c}{(No SH)}& \multicolumn{1}{c}{(SH)}&\multicolumn{1}{c}{(No SH)}&\multicolumn{1}{c}{\makecell[cc]{NPV \\(No SH)}} &\multicolumn{1}{c}{\makecell[cc]{NPR \\(SH)}}&
      \multicolumn{1}{c}{Buy(B)}&\multicolumn{1}{c}{Sell (B)} &       \multicolumn{1}{c}{\makecell[cc]{Buy\\ (000,000)}}&\multicolumn{1}{c}{\makecell[cc]{Sell\\(000,000)}} & \multicolumn{1}{c}{NPV} & \multicolumn{1}{c}{NPR}\\
       \multicolumn{1}{c}{}& \multicolumn{1}{c}{(1)
}& \multicolumn{1}{c}{(2)}&\multicolumn{1}{c}{(3)}&\multicolumn{1}{c}{(4)} &\multicolumn{1}{c}{(5)}&
      \multicolumn{1}{c}{(6)}&\multicolumn{1}{c}{(7)} &       \multicolumn{1}{c}{(8)}&\multicolumn{1}{c}{(9)}&\multicolumn{1}{c}{(10)}&\multicolumn{1}{c}{(11)}\\ \midrule
    \endfirsthead
\caption{\large{Summary Statistics - continued}}\\ 
\toprule
         \multicolumn{1}{c}{Year}& \multicolumn{2}{c}{Observations}&\multicolumn{1}{c}{No.Firms}&\multicolumn{2}{c}{Mean}& \multicolumn{2}{c}{MarShare\$}   & \multicolumn{2}{c}{MarShare\#} &       \multicolumn{2}{c}{Mark}\\ \cmidrule(lr){2-3} \cmidrule(lr){5-6} \cmidrule(lr){7-8} \cmidrule(lr){9-10} \cmidrule(l){11-12}
         \multicolumn{1}{c}{}& \multicolumn{1}{c}{(No SH)}& \multicolumn{1}{c}{(SH)}&\multicolumn{1}{c}{(No SH)}&\multicolumn{1}{c}{\makecell[cc]{NPV \\(No SH)}} &\multicolumn{1}{c}{\makecell[cc]{NPR \\(SH)}}&
      \multicolumn{1}{c}{Buy(B)}&\multicolumn{1}{c}{Sell (B)} &       \multicolumn{1}{c}{\makecell[cc]{Buy\\ (000,000)}}&\multicolumn{1}{c}{\makecell[cc]{Sell\\(000,000)}} & \multicolumn{1}{c}{NPV} & \multicolumn{1}{c}{NPR}\\
       \multicolumn{1}{c}{}& \multicolumn{1}{c}{(1)
}& \multicolumn{1}{c}{(2)}&\multicolumn{1}{c}{(3)}&\multicolumn{1}{c}{(4)} &\multicolumn{1}{c}{(5)}&
      \multicolumn{1}{c}{(6)}&\multicolumn{1}{c}{(7)} &       \multicolumn{1}{c}{(8)}&\multicolumn{1}{c}{(9)}&\multicolumn{1}{c}{(10)}&\multicolumn{1}{c}{(11)}\\ \midrule
      \endhead
       \midrule
    \multicolumn{12}{r}{\footnotesize\itshape       
                        Continue on the next page}
\endfoot
    \bottomrule
    \multicolumn{12}{l}{SH = Shareholder}
\endlastfoot
1994    & 2,822                 & 3,531              & 1,392                 & -0.086                & -0.085                & 0.531            & 1.376                                                               & 158.712       & 286.982        & -0.443 & -0.288 \\
1995    & 3,766                 & 4,724              & 1,631                 & -0.233                & -0.232                & 0.281            & 3.191                                                               & 58.814        & 499.643        & -0.838 & -0.789 \\
1996    & 4,993                 & 6,114              & 2,118                 & -0.181                & -0.181                & 0.391            & 4.946                                                               & 72.252        & 2006.669       & -0.854 & -0.930 \\
1997    & 5,814                 & 6,999              & 2,350                 & -0.211                & -0.210                & 0.577            & 6.954                                                               & 80.721        & 1596.603       & -0.847 & -0.904 \\
1998    & 7,317                 & 8,800              & 2,685                 & 0.017                 & 0.018                 & 0.936            & 12.013                                                              & 132.938       & 2244.135       & -0.855 & -0.888 \\
1999    & 10,716                & 12,459             & 3,056                 & 0.069                 & 0.069                 & 1.755            & 17.062                                                              & 172.648       & 1471.266       & -0.813 & -0.790 \\
2000    & 20,588                & 23,242             & 3,786                 & -0.007                & -0.006                & 2.992            & 35.909                                                              & 348.423       & 1635.910       & -0.846 & -0.649 \\
2001    & 17,613                & 19,787             & 3,194                 & -0.149                & -0.149                & 1.531            & 21.781                                                              & 261.413       & 1383.436       & -0.869 & -0.682 \\
2002    & 15,837                & 17,773             & 2,976                 & -0.105                & -0.105                & 1.229            & 14.055                                                              & 227.652       & 973.902        & -0.839 & -0.621 \\
2003    & 14,205                & 15,989             & 2,584                 & -0.241                & -0.241                & 1.060            & 18.975                                                              & 114.725       & 1035.963       & -0.894 & -0.801 \\
2004    & 18,017                & 20,370             & 3,197                 & -0.246                & -0.246                & 1.043            & 21.405                                                              & 130.550       & 1093.540       & -0.907 & -0.787 \\
2005    & 17,743                & 19,976             & 3,145                 & -0.231                & -0.230                & 1.924            & 20.957                                                              & 214.510       & 1029.413       & -0.832 & -0.655 \\
2006    & 19,013                & 21,275             & 3,200                 & -0.259                & -0.259                & 1.969            & 27.839                                                              & 126.122       & 1096.229       & -0.868 & -0.794 \\
2007    & 23,753                & 25,662             & 3,407                 & -0.160                & -0.160                & 3.210            & 31.636                                                              & 250.604       & 1329.962       & -0.816 & -0.683 \\
2008    & 30,537                & 30,565             & 3,292                 & -0.064                & -0.063                & 7.171            & 20.560                                                              & 784.786       & 884.918        & -0.483 & -0.060 \\
2009    & 22,468                & 22,469             & 2,398                 & -0.181                & -0.180                & 1.718            & 23.160                                                              & 457.969       & 1058.823       & -0.862 & -0.396 \\
2010    & 27,574                & 27,573             & 2,789                 & -0.216                & -0.215                & 2.941            & 39.861                                                              & 1575.958      & 1894.168       & -0.863 & -0.092 \\
2011    & 28,544                & 28,544             & 2,953                 & -0.183                & -0.183                & 3.409            & 43.146                                                              & 351.198       & 2013.673       & -0.854 & -0.703 \\
2012    & 26,785                & 26,786             & 2,777                 & -0.234                & -0.233                & 4.890            & 49.250                                                              & 465.384       & 1886.073       & -0.819 & -0.604 \\
2013    & 28,140                & 28,144             & 2,813                 & -0.277                & -0.277                & 5.546            & 62.036                                                              & 414.053       & 2194.972       & -0.836 & -0.683 \\
2014    & 23,603                & 23,612             & 2,916                 & -0.264                & -0.264                & 2.624            & 40.205                                                              & 186.281       & 1398.489       & -0.877 & -0.765 \\
2015    & 20,968                & 20,979             & 2,799                 & -0.241                & -0.240                & 2.779            & 37.524                                                              & 179.134       & 1184.230       & -0.862 & -0.737 \\
2016    & 17,190                & 17,792             & 2,449                 & -0.286                & -0.286                & 3.140            & 33.824                                                              & 155.227       & 747.809        & -0.830 & -0.656 \\
2017    & 17,559                & 18,540             & 2,410                 & -0.330                & -0.330                & 2.101            & 43.482                                                              & 111.983       & 963.327        & -0.908 & -0.792 \\
2018    & 16,071                & 17,156             & 2,243                 & -0.289                & -0.289                & 1.931            & 31.389                                                              & 97.476        & 572.353        & -0.884 & -0.709 \\
Overall & 441,636               & 468,861            &                       & -0.187                & -0.187                &                  &                                                                     &               &                &        &         \\ \bottomrule   
\end{longtable}
\end{landscape}


\end{document}
```

Comment: I suspect the the `,` (comma) characters are not decimal markers but thousands-separators. Maybe the OP will clarify what the commas denote.

Answer (score 1):

I am posting the way I solved the problem.

```
\documentclass[10pt,a4paper]{article}
\usepackage{booktabs}
\usepackage[singlelinecheck=false, font={large, bf}]{caption}
\usepackage{array,lscape,longtable}
\usepackage[a4paper, total={6in,10in},top=2cm]{geometry}
\usepackage{siunitx,amsmath,dcolumn}
\newcolumntype{.}[1]{D{.}{.}{2.4}}
\newcolumntype{,}[1]{D{,}{,}{2.4}}
\begin{document}
\begin{landscape}
\vspace*{-1.5cm}
\setlength{\tabcolsep}{5pt}
\begin{longtable}{cc,c,c.c.c.c.c.c.c.c.c.c.c}
```

I kept all other codes intact.
[image]